# How to configure programatically the session tracking modes for Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat7, java-ee-6

I'm using an embedded tomcat server version 7. I want to programmatically configure the server with the session tracking mode (in fact I search a way to get rid of jsessionid i.e neither in the cookies nor in the url).
But there is no a method in **org.apache.catalina.Context** to simply configure this property like in a web.xml descriptor file (I cannot use such file).
So what is the best way to do it?

I tried the above code

```
Context ctxt = tomcat.addWebapp(.......);
ctxt.getServletContext().setSessionTrackingModes(
        my_modes);
```

But this method failed with the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The session tracking modes for context / cannot be set whilst the context is running
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.setSessionTrackingModes(ApplicationContext.java:1235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.setSessionTrackingModes(ApplicationContextFacade.java:611)
```

I tried to use https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Context.html#addApplicationListener(java.lang.String). The listener on contextInitialized set the tracking mode

```
servletContextEvent.getServletContext().setSessionTrackingModes(
        EnumSet.copyOf(sessionTrackingModes));
```

But I don't know how to configure tomcat with an instance of this listener because with the last method **Context.addApplicationListener** the method takes the className of the listener and when running the server fails to instantiate my listener because the absence of an empty constructor (my listener constructor takes the list of sessionTrackingMode.. cannot be configurable)

```
[read-1] ERROR Aug 18 19:10:03 - Error configuring application listener of class xx.xx.xx.SessionTrackingListener
java.lang.InstantiationException: xx.xx.xx.SessionTrackingListener
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:125)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4715)
..............
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: xx.xx.xx.xx.SessionTrackingListener.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
```

So do you suggest a better way to do it

Comment: In general, see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/listeners.html for setting up listeners.  The question I have is why would you want to get rid of jsessionid in the first place?  It is an integral aspect of tracking requests made by multiple users and the container needs that info to function properly.

Comment: Because in the server side I am using a custom internal session implementation,  not a HttpSession and there is another cookies I have added ti identify this cutom session between requests. I am not using HttpSession

Answer (score 0):

Use a SessionTrackingListener. The problem with the one you are using is that it doesn't have a default constructor. It should work if you add a default constructor to it.

Comment: But I need to use the constructor with arguments so if I added a default one I will have NPE

Comment: You can't. How is jersey supposed to know what to pass in when it creates the Listener? You can create a new Class with a static Method, that returns the information you want to use in the Listener. Make sure this information is available when the Listener is created. Then call this method in the listener to retrieve the information where needed.